# Adding `MethodCallExpression` on top of provided `Expression`

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection, expression

I'm having expression tree originating in Linq, e.g. `leCollection.Where(...).OrderBy(...).Skip(n).Take(m)`. Expression looks like:

```
Take(Skip(OrderBy(Where(...), ...), n), m) // you got the idea
```

Now, this is my ideal state that I have `Take` and `Skip` there, but it is not the rule. I would like to add `Take`/`Skip` programmatically if needed.

I came up with way how to change `Take`/`Skip` argument, and I'm even able to add `Skip` under `Take` if I detect it's not present, but I'm struggling to figure out how to add `Take` at the top of expression - I don't know how to recognize I'm actually visiting top expression. Methods I wrote are executed on every method call in tree, so I had to check method name before I do anything with expression.

Here are methods I'm using for altering `Take`/`Skip` and adding `Skip` under `Take`. Those work, I'm now also interested in placing `Take` on top of tree if it's not yet present. Could anyone direct me to any place of wisdom, where I can learn more?

```
public class LeVisitor<TEntity> : ExpressionVisitor
    where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly int? _take;
    private readonly int? _skip;
    private readonly MethodInfo _queryableSkip;

    public LeVisitor(int? take, int? skip)
    {
        // ...
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        return base.VisitMethodCall(AlterTake(AlterSkip(node)));
    }

    private MethodCallExpression AlterTake(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        if (!_take.HasValue || !node.Method.Name.Equals("Take", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            return node;
        }

        Expression innerCall = node.Arguments[0];
        if (_skip != null)
        {
            var innerMethod = innerCall as MethodCallExpression;
            if (innerMethod != null && !innerMethod.Method.Name.Equals("Skip", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                ConstantExpression skipConstant = Expression.Constant(_skip, typeof(int));
                innerCall = Expression.Call(_queryableSkip, new[] { innerCall, skipConstant });
            }
        }

        return node.Update(
            node.Object,
            new[]
            {
                innerCall,
                Expression.Constant(_take, typeof(int))
            });
    }

    private MethodCallExpression AlterSkip(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        if (!_skip.HasValue || !node.Method.Name.Equals("Skip", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            return node;
        }

        return node.Update(
            node.Object,
            new[]
            {
                node.Arguments[0],
                Expression.Constant(_skip, typeof(int))
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `Visit` method and use flag variable to check if this is a very first call to it.
Next code will check a top method and if it's not a `Take` add call to `Queryable.Take`

```
public class AddTakeVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly int takeAmount;
    private bool firstEntry = true;

    public AddTakeVisitor(int takeAmount)
    {
        this.takeAmount = takeAmount;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (!firstEntry)
            return base.Visit(node);

        firstEntry = false;
        var methodCallExpression = node as MethodCallExpression;
        if (methodCallExpression == null)
            return base.Visit(node);

        if (methodCallExpression.Method.Name == "Take")
            return base.Visit(node);

        var elementType = node.Type.GetGenericArguments();
        var methodInfo = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethod("Take", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .MakeGenericMethod(elementType.First());
        return Expression.Call(methodInfo, node, Expression.Constant(takeAmount));
    }
}
```

I've tested it with this code:

```
var exp = (new[] {1, 2, 3}).AsQueryable().Skip(1);
var visitor = new AddTakeVisitor(1);
var modified = visitor.Visit(exp.Expression);
```

`modified.DebugView` looks like this:

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Take(
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Skip(
        .Constant<System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[System.Int32]>(System.Int32[]),
        1),
    1)
```